# Navbar displaying in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, element-plus

I'm currently trying to build a website using vue.js(vue3) and element-plus. I created a Navbar component in a Navbar.vue file and i tried adding it to the App.js file the Navbar keeps displaying in the middle of the page, making everything disorganized.

NB: I'm using a 21" lenovo thinkVision when I split the screen the navbar appears perfectly as it should but when in full screen it moves to the center of the page. I've tried almost everything but still it keeps happening. I even changed pc but still it keeps on appearing on the middle page.[text]

```
App.js

<template>
  <NavbarComponent/>
  <HeroView/>
  <UserSuccessStories/>
  
  <RouterView />
</template>

<script setup>
import {  RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import NavbarComponent from '@/components/Navbar.vue'
import HeroView from '@/views/Heroview.vue'
import UserSuccessStories from '@/components/UserSuccessStories.vue'

</script>

<style >
.el-card__body {
  padding: none !important;
}

</style>
```

```
Navbar.vue

<template>
    <div class="navbar">
        <section>
            <img src="/images/logo1.png" alt="logo" style="width: 200px">

        </section>

        <el-menu default-active="1" 
        class="el-menu-demo" 
        mode="horizontal" 
        @select="handleSelect" 
        :ellipsis="false">
            <el-menu-item index="1">Home</el-menu-item>

            <el-sub-menu index="2">
                <template #title>Courses</template>
                <el-menu-item index="2-1">item one</el-menu-item>
                <el-menu-item index="2-2">item two</el-menu-item>
                <el-menu-item index="2-3">item three</el-menu-item>
            </el-sub-menu>
            
            <el-sub-menu index="3">
                <template #title>Questions</template>
                <el-menu-item index="3-1">item one</el-menu-item>
                <el-menu-item index="3-2">item two</el-menu-item>
                <el-menu-item index="3-3">item three</el-menu-item>
            </el-sub-menu>

            <el-sub-menu index="4">
                <template #title>Questions</template>
                <el-menu-item index="4-1">item one</el-menu-item>
                <el-menu-item index="4-2">item two</el-menu-item>
                <el-menu-item index="4-3">item three</el-menu-item>
            </el-sub-menu>

            <el-menu-item index="5">Pricing</el-menu-item>
        </el-menu>

        <section class="login">

            <el-button type="success" style="background-color: transparent;
            border-color:black; color: black;">Login</el-button>
            <el-button type="success" style="background-color: rgba(168, 192, 39, 1);border: 2px;  border-color: rgba(168, 192, 39, 1)">Register</el-button>

        </section>

        <section>

        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "NavbarComponent"

}
</script>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

function handleSelect(val, event) {
    console.log(val)
}
</script>


<style >
body{
    background-color: rgba(236, 242, 198, 0.6);
  }
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
 
}

.el-menu--horizontal {
    align-items: center;
}

.el-menu--horizontal.el-menu {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.el-menu--horizontal>.el-menu-item.is-active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(168, 192, 39, 1);
    color: rgba(41, 39, 37, 0.9) !important;
}

img{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.login{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    
}
</style>
```

```
Heroview.vue

<template>
    <div class="main">
        <section>
            <h1>Focus <br>Technologies</h1>

            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</h2>

            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam,
                nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
                officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            </P>
        </section>

        <section>
            <img class="pic" src="/images/pic.png" alt="pic">
        </section>

    </div>

    <section class="explore">

        <el-button class="btn1" type="success" style="background-color: transparent;
        border-color:black; color: black;">Explore Courses</el-button>
        <el-button class="btn2" type="success"
            style="background-color: rgba(101, 115, 23, 1);border: 2px;  border-color: rgba(101, 115, 23, 1)">Explore
            Internship</el-button>

    </section>

    <div class="line"></div>


    <div class="card-container1">
        <el-card class="card1">
            <img class="logo" src="/images/zapper.png" />
        </el-card >

        <el-card class="card1">
            <img class="logo" src="/images/spotify.png" />
        </el-card>

        <el-card class="card1">
            <img class="logo" src="/images/zoom.png" />
        </el-card>

        <el-card class="card1">
            <img class="logo" src="/images/amazon.png" />
        </el-card>

        <el-card class="card1">
            <img class="logo" src="/images/adobe.png" />
        </el-card>

        <el-card class="card1">
            <img class="logo" src="/images/notion.png" />
        </el-card>

        <el-card class="card1">
            <img class="logo" src="/images/netflix.png" />
        </el-card>

        
    </div>

</template>



<script>
export default {

    name: 'HeroView'
}
</script>

<script setup>

</script>


<style scoped>
.main {
    display: flex;

}

h1 {
    width: 659px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: 290px;
    margin-left: 161px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 110px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

h2 {
    width: 878px;
    height: 42px;
    margin-left: 161px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 42.36px;
}

p {
    width: 807px;
    height: 210px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30.26px;
    margin-top: 69px;
    margin-left: 161px;
    margin-right: 71px;

}

.pic {
    width: 657px;
    height: 633px;
    margin-top: 290px;
    margin-right: 92px;
    margin-left: 132px;
}


.explore {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 161px;
    margin-top: 71px;
}


.line {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-color: rgba(168, 192, 39, 1);
    width: 1600px;
    margin-top: 136px;
    margin-right: 159px;
    margin-left: 161px;
}

.card-container1 {                  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 1073px;
    height: 94px;
    margin-left: 422px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 47px;
    padding: none;
   
}
.el-card.is-always-shadow {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border:none !important; 
   

}


.el-card__body {
    padding: none !important;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
}
.card1 {
    max-width: 153.29px;
    height: 94px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    background-color: transparent;
    gap: 30px;
    

}

</style>
```

```
UserSuccessStories.vue

<template >
    <div class="uss">
       <h2 class="user-story"> User Success Stories</h2> 

       <div class="user-success">
        <el-card class="usercard" style="width: 480px" shadow="always">
            <img src="/images/uss1.png">
            <img src="/images/usspic1.png">
            <img src="/images/Rose Mark.png"><br>
            <img src="/images/Star.png">
        </el-card>
        
        <el-card style="width: 480px" shadow="hover">Hover</el-card>
        <el-card style="width: 480px" shadow="never">Never</el-card>
      </div>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "UserSuccessStories"
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.uss {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 643px;
    width: 1920%;
}
user-success{
    padding: none !important;
}
   .user-story{
    width: 413px;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 48.41px;
    margin-top: 51px;
    margin-left: 754px;
  
   } 

   .userard {
    padding: none !important;
   }
</style>
```

[This is the view when i have slit the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0SQZ.png)
[This is how it appears when i put it in full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byLfY.png)

i want the fullscreen mode to also appear exactly how the split screen mode appears.

Comment: The only expertise needed for answering your question is `css`. Experts in any of the technologies you tagged your question with won't be able to help (unless they are also proficient in CSS, of course). Consider creating a [mcve] (on codesandbox.io or similar) with the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: FYI: StackOverflow now has executable snippets to use as a sandbox - click the `<>` button in SO's editor. Only post code relevant to the problem in question.

Comment: Does SO snippet have the ability to parse SFC (`.vue`) files, or emulate a node environment (e.g: installing packages), @PeterPointer?

Comment: @tao Vue can be added on the left side. It does not allow for a full project with separate files. But the OP in this case certainly has more of a CSS problem than a vue problem.

Comment: @PeterPointer, agreed, but, in order to provide and test an answer, someone must either take OP's SFCs and put them in a node-like environment, with the appropriate packages and their versions (which we don't know, btw) and hope there's no other package in OP's project adding unknown CSS to the page. If OP provides a [mcve], they have a much higher chance of getting an answer. And doing so in codesandbox.io or similar is more straight forward than in a SO snippet, although it could be repro-ed here.

Comment: @tao Yes I mean everyone agrees that the "minimal" in minimal reproducable example is the import word there. Not faulting anyone for using an external resource, just suggesting to switch to a snippet if CSS is the only apparent problem here.